# Is it possible to calculate linear interpolation between two known points with accelerate framework in swift

Tags: swift, accelerate-framework

as title:
Is it possible to calculate linear interpolation between two known points with accelerate framework in swift

example: a line -> p1(x:0.0, y:0.0) p2(x:100, y:100)
horizon vector = 0 to 100
vertical vector = 0 to 100
when I input X = 50 then output Y= 50

Comment: Although I'm unfamiliar with what are you trying to achieve, but don't you think that you could make it -by applying an equation- by your self?

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32801059/linear-resampling-datapoints-captured-at-fluctuating-time-intervals-to-flxed-ti.

Comment: @MartinR. I read this thread, But I don't have any ideas to put horizon vector and vertical vector for calculating.

Answer (score 1):

There's a `mix` function in simd:

```
public func mix(_ x: float2, _ y: float2, t: Float) -> float2
```